# Suitable term for "has the highest-rating"/"most-popular" (media outlet)?

Tags: terminology

If you want to say:

> He works for a radio station that is the most popular in his country

Popular here does not necessarily mean "well-liked", but rather that it has the highest listenership numbers.

How can you convey this message succinctly, without using the word popular?

Comment: You can rephrase the sentence and remove the relative clause entirely. "He works for the most listened to radio station in his country". (I copy [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-listened-to_radio_programs) style.

Answer (score -1):

He works for the highest-rated radio station in his country.

Comment: That can also be interpreted as the radio station that has the highest user-ratings (reviews).

Comment: @zerohedge Well, I suppose it can, but if you google the quoted phrase "highest rated radio station" together with the word "Arbitron" you will find more than 4,000 hits using the phrase as I meant it. I could find no use of the phrase with the meaning you suggest. One might also substitute, "most listened to", I suppose, but in the context of radio and TV, the word, "ratings" is well understood to mean quantity of ears and eyes.

Comment: Another data point: The search, "highest rated" site:talkers.com, which confines the query to a trade journal on talk radio yields about a 1000 hits.